# getting the video's current vttcue frame information

Tags: html, video, webvtt, vtt

I am trying to build a live video captioning editor and require that I fetch the current video frame's VTTCue information (startTime, endTime, text). How do I go about accomplishing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind. video.textTracks[0].oncuechange is what i needed to accomplish my goal.